# Interpretation of $|V|\,|E|$ for bipartite graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

**Background:** the question is motivated by a result in statistical mechanics. I am working with a generalized exclusion process with a fixed number of particles $k$ on a finite graph $G'=(V,E')$, which can be seen as a Markov chain in discrete time where in any time step at most one particel moves. The value of a certain energy for a given particle configuration is given by the inverse of its probability under the stationary distribution and the maximal value is propotional to $|V|\,|E|$ for a bipartite subgraph $G=(V,E)$ of $G'$ where for some configuration of particles $U\subset V$, with $|U|=k$, the edges in $E$ are given by all edges in $G'$ between $U$ and $V\setminus U$.

**Now my question:** is there a graph theoretical or combinatorical interpretation of this term $|V|\,|E|$ for a bipartite graph $G=(V,E)$?